# Missing android_winusb.inf file; trying to setup environment for Kindle Fire dev

Tags: android, sdk, kindle-fire

I'm following the instructions at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/getting-started-with-kindle-fire-development/ describing how to setup a dev. environment for the Kindle Fire.  I'm stuck at the step "[Windows] Step 2: Using the Google USB Driver" however.  The Android SDK app. indicates the Google USB driver is installed, but I don't have the file android_winusb.inf.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

For me, the android_winusb.inf file was not in the %USERPROFILE%.android directory.  It was in a subfolder of the Android SDK directory, specifically:

```
C:\android\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
```

and

```
C:\android\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
```

with my Android SDK installed in C:\android.

I'm not sure why there are two, but it appeared the one in the extras folder was newer, looking at DriverVer inside the file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but, I recently had to find this and found my android_winusb.inf file at: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can see hidden files/folders:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/

The ini file you're looking for is in the .android folder in you home directory. To find your home directory use this in the command line:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

Navigate to the location it displays and modify the file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already had show hidden files on and the file is definitely not there.  Anything else I can try?

Comment: If it's missing, try creating it and then restarting adb.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK manager
Select SDK Platform Tools
Scroll down, select Google USB driver
Install
Hey Presto!